# CCActionDelay in End Game Sequence

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccaction

My hero sprite is on a physics sprite. If the player (user) doesn't move the hero for 2 seconds while touching the sprite I want to end the game. In the update method I am checking to see if the two sprites are touching for longer than 2 seconds and if true run "game over" action. This is the code

```
if( TWO SPRITES ARE TOUCHING && USER ISN"T TOUCHING THE SCREEN ){
    [_hero runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:[CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:2.0f],
                      _gameOverAction,
                      nil]];

}
```

The end game action runs even if the user is holding down. Basically if you don't touch the screen to move the sprite the game should end. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code as soon as two sprites are touching and the user isn't touching the screen it will quick off the action. It will happen in 2 seconds no matter what as it is never cancelled.

What you need to do instead is keep a variable of the time it last happened and check to see if 2 seconds have passed since then in your update loop. If it has then you can call the game over method.